# jQuery datepicker not showing properly in Rails app

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui

I have a Rails 3.2.14 app in which in different forms I'm using the jQuery datepicker element.  On my development environment the datepicker shows up properly as below:

[image]

In my production environment, the datepicker is skewed and looks like the following:

[image]

[image]

My development and production environments are identical except for the fact the production environment is using SSL/encryption to serve content.

I'm not sure if the SSL is a problem or not but this behavior seemed to start once we encrypted our app/site.

Here's an excerpt of my application.html.erb where I'm calling jquery-ui stylesheet from Google's CDN.

```
    <title><%= title %></title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" ,"application", :media => "all" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  </head>
```

Also an excerpt of my application.js to show I'm including jQuery properly

```
    //= require jquery
    //= require gritter
    //= require jquery_ujs
    //= require twitter/bootstrap
    //= require jquery-ui
    //= require gmaps4rails/all
    //= require_tree .

$(function (){
  $(".select").select2({
        placeholder: "Select One",
        allowClear: true
  });

  $("button").on("click", function() { $(this).addClass("disabled") });

  $('#start_date_select').datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});
  $('#end_date_select').datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});
  $( "#patient_dob" ).datepicker({
      dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
      yearRange: '1900:2015',
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true
    });
 $( "#transfer_date" ).datepicker({
      dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
      yearRange: '2014:2015',
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true
    });
});
```

Again I'm not exactly sure when this behavior started.  It may have been when we encrypted the site, but one of the employees said it's happened a month prior to the SSL certificate being installed.

I can deploy the codebase to another identical server and the behavior does not happen, but that server is also not encrypted.

Anyone have any ideas on why this is happening?

Comment: Thats because of the style...check the style or the correct property and make sure about yours javascripts also if u use chrome press f12 and check if shows an error

Answer (score 1):

Discovered the problem by inspecting one of the datepicker elements.  The google jquery-ui stylesheet I was calling in my application.html.erb file was being called via http so the site was blocking the stylesheet.

I called the same stylesheet with https and now the datepicker works properly.

All I had to do was change the stylesheet call directly on the server to the following:

```
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css
```

Problem solved.  Now time to put it into git, and deploy tomorrow.